# How to measure time in reference frame with clock?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time, time-dilation

I considered example of time dilation with light clock. I have a question about measuring time in reference frame with clock.

[image]

If we know that clock move from A to B in the reference frame with clock then what time of motion is measured in this reference frame? (In non-moving reference frame time is $\Delta t$)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on virtually any website that introduces special relativity, so I won't give it to you. Instead, I encourage you to work it out for yourself. Consider the diagonal path followed by light in the stationary frame, which the light takes Δ to follow. Then compare that to the shorter up and down path the light follows in the frame of the clock. Given that the speed of light is the same in each frame, you should be able to work out the time in the frame of the clock using nothing more complicated than Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: I supposed that time is $\Delta t0$ because light reach at end point at this time.  But I think it's wrong. I have no more guess for this example.